# After conformal compactification, do null geodesics intersect future null infinity nonasymptotically?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology, geodesics

I was going through [this paper](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1271271792) and was worried about an assumption in the main proof (Theorem 3.1), where they assume null geodesics intersect the boundary extension after conformal compactification transversally. However, would one not expect null geodesics to intersect the extension asymptotically and therefore not have a point of intersection?

Comment: The idea is a compact space is one that contains its limit points and is bounded. If it intersects the extension asymptotically, the would-be point of intersection is a limit point of the space, and is therefore in the space, and is therefore a point of intersecion.

Comment: Isn't the idea that the null geodesic approaches the boundary asymptotically, so we cannot say where it meets the boundary, for example a spiral that approaches a circle asymptotically from the inside

Comment: Sometimes you compactify a space by adding a single point at infinity. For example the real number plane is not compact. To compactify it, you map it to a sphere in the standard way ([picture](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-compactification-of-R-2_fig1_243540145))and add the point at infinity at the top of the sphere. It doesn't matter which way you approach infinity on the plane. On the compact sphere, that maps to approaching the one and only point at infinity.